# Inconsistent node length from polygons in Osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

My question is pretty straightforward: I have a network formed from 2 polygons and another that only contains only one of the two polygons from the previous network. If I check how many nodes are in one polygon in the network that has 2 polygons I get 9735 nodes. However if I check how many nodes are in the same polygon but in the network that has only one polygon I get 9719. I don't understand why the difference, they should be the same.

**Here is the code:**

```
cities = ox.geocode_to_gdf(['Município de Lisboa', 'Município da Amadora'])
whole_polygon = cities.unary_union #unary union of both geometries
lisbon_pol = cities['geometry'].iloc[0] #geometry of just lisbon
amadora_pol = cities['geometry'].iloc[1]

G = ox.graph_from_polygon(whole_polygon, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
G_nx = nx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G)

nodes_in_lx = nodes[nodes.within(lisbon_pol)] 
print(len(nodes_in_lx)) # This gives 9735 nodes

G_lx = ox.graph_from_polygon(lisbon_pol, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
print(len(G_lx)) # This gives 9719 nodes
```

What contributes more to the inconsistency is the fact that if I sum the nodes from the individual polygons I get less nodes than the nodes in the `whole_polygon`:

```
print(len(G)) # gives 12812

G_am = ox.graph_from_polygon(amadora_pol, network_type='drive', simplify=True)
print(len(G_am)) # gives 3071 nodes
```

Therefore: `3071 + 9719 =12790 and not 12812`

I don't understand where is the mistake or if there is any.

Comment: Do you get the same effect with `simplify=False`?

Comment: Yes, it still gives me a different number of nodes

Comment: In that case, could you try to use `retain_all=True`?

Comment: cross-ref https://stackoverflow.com/q/62963574/7321942

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand where is the mistake or if there is any.

There is no mistake. This is a standard "boundary" problem in delineating the artificial extents of real-world spatial graphs. Look at the nodes that differ between `nodes_in_lx` and `G_lx`. Notice where they all are? Right along the border between your two study areas.

OSMnx does various things to mitigate artificial periphery effects when constructing the graph models. You can peruse the source code for details. But likely the most important here in your case has to do with deciding what spatial elements are "in" or "out" of the requested study area. For example, if an edge traversed the boundary, should it be included or not? If it's not included, what happens to its incident nodes?

When you merge the two polygons together before querying/constructing the graph, you do not have to deal with any such "periphery" questions for that internal boundary separating them. But when you download the data for just one of those two polygons directly, you *do* have to deal with such questions. Hence, there can be slight differences due to the presence or lack of that internal boundary.